# Research Collaboration Outside Academia

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, research

I am trying to brainstorm ways for folks interested in studying or researching math as a *hobby* to connect with each other. The pleasures of doing math in a social setting is something I have missed since leaving academia, and I know there are others who feel similarly. I am imagining an online platform where:

1. People with an interest in learning some topic could select a textbook and syllabus, and hold weekly meetings to discuss the material.
2. People with common research interests could connect and collaborate on academic papers.
3. People could organize "adult [math circles](https://mathcircles.org/about/)"
4. People interested in an online talk or lecture series could attend together, and meet afterwards to discuss the topic.

In other words, the idea would be to recreate some of the collaborative/social opportunities that exist in a university. If you are interested in this concept, please say so in the comments and give your ideas for how this might work! Is there an existing social networking site that would be well-suited to this project? What kinds of features would you want to see? Does anything like this already exist?

Comment: Why don't you just join the conferences/research meetings in a nearby university? Most university I know are quite open, as long as you are serious and rigorous enough in research.

Comment: @High GPA I think this could work for some people. In my case, the closest university is about an hour away, and none of the faculty have research interests that overlap with mine.

Comment: What do you think about the site Art Of Problem Solving?

Comment: I've always wondered why this isn't a more popular thing. From what I heard, those collaborative internet projects in years past to work on the Twin Prime conjecture and others were enormously successful, and then I haven't heard much about that approach since.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I think of AoPS as being primarily for younger students, but perhaps that is not the case?

Comment: @AriHerman I’m sorry I misunderstood your question. I overlooked the words “researching” and “left academia” so came to the wrong conclusion. You’re right, AoPS is for younger students.

Comment: As a student who has had a lot of experience self-studying and has personally seen what he's about to suggest in action, I would say that Discord is the best platform right now that will give you what you want. It has essentially everything you need. You can create servers for people, there are plenty of in-built features that will allow you modify a given server so that it suits your purposes, there are bots for literally everything, including music & latex.

Comment: I am a big fan of self-studying, even as a university student, and I think that Discord is probably the best place to achieve what you want. Collaborative work has been very easy, at least for me, on Discord. Initially, there is a bit of difficulty as you're trying to figure everything out but I am really interested in something like this so I wouldn't mind contributing to making a server where all of this is possible.

Comment: @Abhi Thank you for telling me about Discord. I created an account and it DOES look very promising. I see that there is already a "Mathematics" serve, that appears to be at least superficially similar to what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Abhi's comments, I'm looking into Discord as a possible place to organize the kinds of collaboration mentioned in my original post. Here is one idea of how a Discord server could be set up:

1. Keep technical discussions within private audio/video channels with small numbers of members (3-10 maybe). This way, the members of a private channel can get to know each other, develop a rapport and collaborate on more extensive study or research projects. This would distinguish it from places like Stack Exchange, where most conversations are public and off-topic socializing is discouraged.
2. Public channels should be used primarily to post invitations for specific collaborations (study groups, research groups, people interested in discussing and attending an online seminar together, etc.).

=================================================================

These are just ideas. I'd love to hear feedback and alternatives. Do others think Discord would be the right choice of platform? How would *you* want to see a Discord server set up, if the goal was to promote social connections and collaborations?